# how get a specific value from a string?

Tags: java, string

i have have a string looks :

```
 mystring = "<EQHO state="degraded"...> at /NE[1]/EQHO[2]/@state to <EQHO state="working"...> at /NE[1]/EQHO[1]/@state"
```

and i want to get this value :

**value**="NE[1]/EQHO[1]"

how can i achieve that ? 
thanks

Comment: What kind of format is this? XML?

Comment: @Flown its a simple string

Comment: Where do you get this "simple" String? Because it's not a simple one. Maybe give it a try with [regex](https://regex101.com/r/lP2tF4/2)

Comment: Try this: `mystring.substring(mystring.lastIndexOf("at /")+4, mystring.lastIndexOf("/@"))` but you probably should use a more generic solution.

Comment: this string is the result of comparing two xml files using xmlunit . the problem that i can get the first value ( NE[1]/EQHO[2] ) using substring(mystring.indexOf("> at /")+6, mystring.indexOf("/@")) but i dont know how to get the value (NE[1]/EQHO[1])

Comment: @Titus it works thanks can u post ur comment as an answer so i can  accept it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mystring.substring(mystring.lastIndexOf("at /")+4, mystring.lastIndexOf("/@"))
```

but you probably should use a more generic solution. To extract all the section that have this format you can use something like this:

```
String mystring = "<EQHO state=\"degraded\"...> at /NE[1]/EQHO[2]/@state to <EQHO state=\"working\"...> at /NE[1]/EQHO[1]/@state";
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
while(mystring.indexOf("at /") < mystring.indexOf("/@")){
    String val = mystring.substring(mystring.indexOf("at /") + 4, mystring.indexOf("/@"));
    values.add(val);
    mystring = mystring.substring(mystring.indexOf("/@")+2);
}
System.out.println(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value of a string like this

```
mystring = "NE[1]/EQHO[1]";
```

Remember to include the semicolon!